# Google App Script Exceeded maximum execution time error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get the difference of two dates and post them in a column.
My sheet has 2000 rows.
I am getting Exceeded maximum execution time error after reaching 1500 rows.
Please help me resolve this.
Thanks

````
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

  // Loop through each row starting from the second row
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var dayAndMonth = sheet.getRange("F" + i).getValue();
    dayAndMonth=Utilities.formatDate(dayAndMonth, 'Asia/Kolkata', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    
    // Ensure dayAndMonth is a string
    dayAndMonth = dayAndMonth.toString();

    // Convert day and month to a date object
    var dayAndMonthArray = dayAndMonth.split("/");
    var month = parseInt(dayAndMonthArray[1]) - 1; // Months in JavaScript are zero-based
    var day = parseInt(dayAndMonthArray[0]);
    var dateWithCurrentYear = new Date(currentYear, month, day);

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var differenceInMilliseconds = dateWithCurrentYear - currentDate;

    // Convert milliseconds to days
    var differenceInDays = (Math.floor(differenceInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

    // Set the result in column O
    sheet.getRange("M" + i).setValue(differenceInDays);
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from the sheet and writing is a very slow operation, compared to calculations. You need to batch them:

1. read with `getValues()`,
2. calculate the difference and store it in `output`, and
3. write all rows at once with `setValues()`.

This is a quick rewrite of your code. Without sample data I cannot test it, so you might need to adjust it a bit.

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

// Get all data from column F at once starting from the second row
var range = sheet.getRange("F2:F" + lastRow);
var data = range.getValues(); // This is a 2D array

var output = []; // Array to hold the computed differences

// Process each row in the data array
data.forEach(function(row) {
  var dayAndMonth = row[0];
  dayAndMonth = Utilities.formatDate(dayAndMonth, 'Asia/Kolkata', 'dd/MM/yyyy');

  // Ensure dayAndMonth is a string
  dayAndMonth = dayAndMonth.toString();

  // Convert day and month to a date object
  var dayAndMonthArray = dayAndMonth.split("/");
  var month = parseInt(dayAndMonthArray[1]) - 1; // Months in JavaScript are zero-based
  var day = parseInt(dayAndMonthArray[0]);
  var dateWithCurrentYear = new Date(currentYear, month, day);

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var differenceInMilliseconds = dateWithCurrentYear - currentDate;

  // Convert milliseconds to days
  var differenceInDays = Math.floor(differenceInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  // Store the result in the output array
  output.push([differenceInDays]); // setValues requires a 2D array
});

// Set all the computed differences in column M at once
var outputRange = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + (1 + output.length));
outputRange.setValues(output);
```

I do not know your use case, but it looks like you can achieve the same result with Google Sheets formulas (example for one row):

1. Subtract one from another: `=INT(NOW() - F2)`, or
2. Use `DAYS` function ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296?hl=en)) `=DAYS(NOW(), F2)`

Answer (score 0):

Difference in days between current  date and column 5 stored in column M

```
function  differenceInDays() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lr = sh.getLastRow();
  const dt = new Date();//currrent date
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1 , sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r, i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[5]);//col f
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    return [Math.floor((Math.abs(dtv - dv)) / 86400000)];
  });
  sh.getRange(2,13,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//col m
}
```